# Parachuting onto the Martian surface from Phobos

Tags: story-identification

Either a story or novel from the late 50s or early 60s concerning the protagonist launching himself from Phobos using only leg power, and then parachuting onto the Martian surface. I need to know. "It's like having an itch that you can't scratch."

Comment: In Neil R. Jones's ["Escape from Phobos"](https://archive.org/stream/Wonder_Stories_v04n09_1933-02#page/n19/mode/2up) a convict escapes Phobos and lands on Mars with spaceship and improvised parachute made from bed sheets. But he doesn't jump off Phobos "using only leg power", he has rockets strapped to his suit; and the story is too early to be the one you're looking for, as it was published in a 1933 *Wonder Stories* and apparently never reprinted.